# Accessing fields in windows applications

Tags: .net, powershell, vbscript, automation

I am using a test automation software called testcomplete to enter and read values in fields of a windows .net application.
Is there a way to do this task with the help of simple tools? or scripting or programming languages?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [UI Automation PowerShell Extensions](https://uiautomation.codeplex.com/).

```
Get-UIAWindow -ProcessName $processname | Get-UIAButton -Name $btnName | Invoke-UIAButtonClick
Get-UIAWindow -Name $windowTitle | Get-UIAChildWindow | Get-UIATextBox -AutomationID ServerBox | Set-UIATextBoxText -Text "text"
```